# Why there isn't parentheses for methods inside of promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why there is no parentheses for console.log inside of then block of promise?
How does it know that what should it log?

```
const Category = require('./models/category');
const cat = Category.find({}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: It's syntactic sugar for: `Category.find({}).then(x => console.log(x));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's passing a function *reference* as a callback. `console.log` refers to a function *to be called* when the promise resolves as opposed to actually calling `console.log`.

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript. They can be passed around. Just like you would do `then(x => console.log(x))`. If you call it before-hand, it will be necessarily evaluated before (and its return value passed):

```
promise.then(console.log()) // Called immediately, undefined passed to then
```

Note that it's not *exactly* the same as `then(x => console.log(x))`. Any context is lost because the callee has no way to recover that from just a function reference. Though this doesn't have an effect here AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to the function that will be called after `Category.find()`. The value passed to it will be the result of the find.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `console.log()` inside the `then` callback would output nothing in the console. Usually, you pass an anonymous or arrow function to the callback argument, but since `console.log` can pretty much have anything as a parameter, you just have to pass the name of the function so the Promise can execute it later.